# How do I unlock the different characters?

Tags: heart-and-slash

I have searched but I've only been able to find how a couple of the characters are unlocked. Does anyone know definitively how to unlock all 5 locked characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some more, I found a [guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618793931) that was posted on steam.